# How to update session values without signing out?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

With [NextAuth.js](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth), how can I update a value inside the session object without signing out and in again?

For example, once a user signs in, I am using the URL stored in the session to display the avatar of the user.

I am also offering the user to change his avatar, so I would like the `session.user.image` to be updated and persistent with the new path of the avatar. I am storing all the data in MongoDB. How can I achieve that? Right now the only solution is to ask the user to sign out and sign in again but that doesn't sound like an acceptable solution to me :)

My first idea would be to update this session object once the user updates his avatar but I can't find out how to do that.

```
import React from 'react'
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from 'next-auth/client'

export default function Page() {
  const [ session, loading ] = useSession()

  return <>
    {session && <>
      <img src={session.user.image} />
      <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
    </>}
  </>
}
```

Comment: hey @Armel have you solved the problem? if not i will create a bounty

Comment: Hi @airsoftFreak, no unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is to modify data before sending session data to client.
By using next-auth session callback we can easily do so.

```js
callbacks: {
      session: async (session, user) => {
      
        const userDatabase = await CreateAccount.findOne({
          email: user.email,
        }); //finding user in DB.
        
        const userData = {
          name: userDatabase.username,
          email: userDatabase.email,
          image: userDatabase.avatar,
          id: userDatabase._id,
        } // creating payload
        
        session.user = userData; //sending payload as session
        
        return Promise.resolve(session);
      },
    },
```

Comment: What if the request to the backend fails? Now the frontend and backend have different user values. The app will crash or have problems on it's next request to the backend. I found you basically have to sign out the user and then sign them back in again if they are going to do profile changes.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not recommended to modify the session outside the [`next-auth`'s config](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options) (commonly specified in the `pages/api/auth/[...nextAuth].js` file), as it can lead to security issues.

If you store the `next-auth` session in a database (i.e. [`session.strategy = "database"`](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#session)), then the best option is to probably update the session directly in the database.

However, if you store the session in `next-auth`'s encrypted JWT, then re-authenticating the user and issuing a new JWT with the updated information may be the safest approach.

**That said, you can directly update the JWT token** by:

1. Grab the current token value from the cookie
2. Update values in the token
3. Create a new encrypted JWT based on the updated token while preserving the old values like expiration (`exp`), issued at (`iat`), ...
4. Check if the app runs on HTTPS or HTTP
5. Decide based on step 4 if the cookie name is `"__Secure-next-auth.session-token"` or `"next-auth.session-token"`
6. Replace the original cookie value with the new encrypted JWT

The [cookie name](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/62f672ae30fb389c1a81f484f2dad7a3e2a6a662/packages/next-auth/src/jwt/index.ts#L73-L77) and implementation varies in local, server and Vercel environments.

Here's an example what this would look like:

```js
// pages/api/update-user-to-premium.js

import { EncryptJWT } from "jose";
import hkdf from "@panva/hkdf";
import { serialize } from "cookie";
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    // 1. Get current token
    const token = await getToken({ req });
    // Example structure of the "token"
    // {
    //     sub: '{3d19bdd6-4764-40e6-b09e-41x7029bceed}',
    //     email: 'example@example.com',
    //     isPremiumUser: false
    //     iat: 1673862936,
    //     exp: 1676454936,
    //     jti: '881e5517-90b6-4430-8270-60f0b880f996'
    // }

    // 2. Update the token except "sub", "iat", "exp" and "jti"
    token.isPremiumUser = true;

    // 3. Create a new encrypted JWT token with the updated value(s)
    const newToken = await encode(token, process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET);

    // 4. Is the app running with HTTPS or HTTP?
    const secureCookie = process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL?.startsWith("https://") ?? !!process.env.VERCEL

    // 5. Specify the Cookie name based on HTTPS or HTTP
    // "next-auth" adds a prefix of `__Secure-` in HTTPS environments
    const cookieName = secureCookie ? "__Secure-next-auth.session-token" : "next-auth.session-token";

    // 6. Replace the next-auth session cookie with the new value
    const cookie = serialize(cookieName, newToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: "/",
        maxAge: token.exp,
        sameSite: "lax",
        secure: secureCookie
    });
    res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie);

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully updated user to premium" });
}

/**
 * Modify "next-auth" `encode` method to manullay set JWT claims
 * @see https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/main/packages/next-auth/src/jwt/index.ts#L17
 */
async function encode(token, secret) {
    const encryptionSecret = await getDerivedEncryptionKey(secret); // Create a cryptographical random secret key using a predictable random secret.
    return await new EncryptJWT(token)
        .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "dir", enc: "A256GCM" })
        .setSubject(token.sub) // set "sub" Subject claim
        .setIssuedAt(token.iat) // adds "iat" to the JWT with current timestamp
        .setExpirationTime(token.exp) // adds "exp" to the JWT - timestamp format
        .setJti(token.jti) // set the "jti claim" - allows for replay protection/blacklist
        .encrypt(encryptionSecret);
}

/**
 * Copy & Pasted from "next-auth" since it's not exported
 * Create a cryptographical random secret key using a predictable random secret.
 * @see https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/main/packages/next-auth/src/jwt/index.ts#L119
 * @param {string} secret Random string secret, e.g. "Whale-Banana-69"
 * @returns {Promise<Uint8Array(32)>} A cryptographically secure Uint8Array(32) representation of the input secret, e.g. transforms "Whale-Banana-69" into "Uint8Array(32) [189,67,29,228,...]"
 */
async function getDerivedEncryptionKey(secret) {
    return await hkdf(
        "sha256",
        secret,
        "",
        "NextAuth.js Generated Encryption Key",
        32
    );
}
```

The above code uses `next-auth`'s internal [`encode`](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/main/packages/next-auth/src/jwt/index.ts#L17) method, which creates an encrypted JWT based off a [derived encryption key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/40767) instead of using the plain `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` value for encryption.

Since `next-auth` uses `HttpOnly` cookies, this code obviously only works in API routes, and should obviously not be attempted to make it work client side for security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to update the user object manually. Check the following link to get an idea on how the callbacks of next-auth work https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks - A possible approach is to update the user in the jwt()/session() callback and adjust the information of the user yourself.

As for now I have not found a function to trigger an automatic update of the user object in relation to the database.

Answer (score 0):

in my case im making apyment on my website after that i want to modify the session when i do session.user.subscribe=true; its works if i dont reload the page, when i reload the page i get the previos vale subscribe=false, now according to u i can n=modify session via user in callbacks but how am i gong to know that the payment has been made in those callbacks, we are trapped at this moment.

if i signout and signin back my subscribe value inside session will get updated automatically