# update the user value in the next auth session when updating data

Tags: authentication, session, next.js, next-auth

I have a page to update user data, everything is running correctly and the data has changed with the latest in the database.  But the value in the next auth session does not change, how to synchronize the newly updated user data with the user data in the next auth session

Comment: did you solve this? this site is dead, only 7 views on this question

Comment: I can't finish it yet. For now I'm tricking using id because its nature doesn't change, but I still need an answer to solve this case

Comment: I've just written a solution to a similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75134483/3673659

Comment: The easiest way is just to log the user out with signOut(). I redirect them to a "success" page with a useEffect() hook that has a time delay setTimeout() of 3 seconds. Say "We will log you out in 3 secs to refresh the profile, please sign in again". Not great but easy.

Answer (score 5):

First you have to update the data on `[...nextauth].js`
It keeps track of user with the server session, but you want fresh data from your server. Here is how I did it :

```
callbacks.session = async function session({ session, token }) {
  // we can fetch info from back end here to add it to the sessio
  session.user = token.user;
  session.jti = token.jti;

  // If user is logged, we refresh his session
  if (token?.user?.id) {
    const url = 
   routes.api.entities.shop.get.byId.build(token?.user?.id);
    let apiResp = await axios.get(url, {});
    session.user = { ...apiResp.data };
    token.user = { ...apiResp.data };
  }

  return session;
};
```

So here, the session that should have been the old one of the server is replaced by the one of my DB.

Then, you have to update it client side.

The data on client side does update if you click on another tab and click again on your tab.

It seems useless, but what about automating it ?

Just use this :

```
const reloadSession = () => {
  const event = new Event("visibilitychange");
  document.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

And calling it directly on your react page will update everything.

```
reloadSession();
```