# How to update Next-auth session from my other API endpoint

Tags: session, next.js, next-auth

I'm using Next-auth with JWT to allow users to sign in via Oauth.

However, I then want to allow users to sign in to a *second* Oauth provider without overwriting the first session.

I was never able to make Next-auth allow it, even with [these tips](https://github.com/rexfordessilfie/next-auth-account-linking/blob/main/src/pages/api/auth/%5B...nextauth%5D.ts).

So I took another approach and installed `simple-oauth2` alongside next-auth. Now:

1. The user signs in via next-auth
2. On a logged-in page, the user clicks a link (provided by `simple-oauth2`) to sign in to *another* Oauth provider (Amazon).
3. The `simple-oauth2` redirect URI is `${baseUrl}/api/alexaOauthCallback`, so that's where Amazon sends the code.
4. The `${baseUrl}/api/alexaOauthCallback` successfully exchanges a code for an access token.
5. At this point, how can I save that access token to a session property called "amazonAccessToken" within next-auth?

I even tried calling this within my `alexaOauthCallback` endpoint, but the new session didn't take hold:

```
/**
 * https://medium.com/@matjarzebski/update-session-in-nextauth-js-server-site-858b5ea4ec
 */
export async function updateSession(newSession: CustomSession) {
  console.log({ newSession });
  await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/auth/session`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      csrfToken: await getCsrfToken(),
      data: newSession,
    }),
  });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65287856/470749 and https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/8254#issuecomment-1732624186 might be related.